# Getting an older Eclipse plugin version from its repo URL

Tags: eclipse-plugin, sapui5

When installing new software in Eclipse, it always installs the latest version, however I need to use the very exact same version of a package as the client, which is quite outdated.

Updating the client's plugin is out of question, so, is there any way for me to downgrade a package or, at least, get an older version from the repo? I know I can install a plugin in offline mode, but first I need to get the correct version from somewhere.

The URL from which I want to get the plugin is https://tools.hana.ondemand.com/mars and as of today it displays version 1.40.11 for sapui5 libs.

Comment: Sadly, I really need to use Eclipse.

Comment: FYI: _SAPUI5 Tools for Eclipse_ is deprecated now. https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/609fd015eaf64bd2a4a5c0331590eb4c Is this question still relevant?